# Dual-flush Toilet Not Filling Up Properly

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet

Here is the video I recorded of my toilet: [Toilet Problems](https://youtu.be/iFsR5KEpINI)

So about a month ago our dual-flush toilet suddenly stopped filling up properly. It takes forever to fill up and it doesn't even fill up properly anyway. What I have seen is that if I flush and I turn off the water supply, wait about five seconds, and turn it back on, the toilet fills up like normal and properly. If I flush again, then the water just fills up slowly again. So I'm not sure if someone could help me figure out what the problem could be. This is the first time having a dual-flush toilet and I'm not really sure what to do...

Comment: You are referencing the filling of the tank, yes? Is it just filling slow, or is there any other issue (like not filling all the way)?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Yes the tank is just filling very slowly and because the tank is filling up slowly the water in the actual toilet is low as well. The toilet doesn't fill up the way it should either.

Comment: Could you post a picture of the components inside the tank, and also of the water supply valve and supply line?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I'll shoot a video and give you the link to the video! Give me a moment...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Here is the video I recorded of my toilet: https://youtu.be/iFsR5KEpINI

Comment: Awesome video. I concur with @iggy, you need to replace the fill valve. It does really look like you could use a generic replacement like the Fluidmaster 400 series, available at almost any hardware store. Shut off water supply, flush, use sponges &/or towels to sop up all water from tank, disconnect flex supply line at bottom inlet to valve (unscrew), pull the little plastic 1/4" hose out of the flush valve, unscrew hex nut under tank to remove entire fill valve, take to hardware/plumbing shop (not "big-box"), compare to Fluidmaster fill valve which is adjustable in all ways and should fit.

Comment: PS- you should maybe grab a replacement flex supply line while you are at the shop. They sometimes don't seal when attempting to reuse. get a braided stainless one, and don't over-tighten when installing.

Comment: Similar question: [Why does this toilet fill valve leak around the top?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/32052/why-does-this-toilet-fill-valve-leak-around-the-top)

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry, dual flush toilets aren't any different. It sounds like your Fill Valve (the tall thing on the left) is on its way out. You can do a new one with just big pliers & you'll need to replace the water hose from the wall to the toilet. $30 & 30-minutes, at the most, should get you back to normal. Or, call Roto Rooter if you don't do that stuff. It's common but not too predictable, every 10-years is a good preventative rule.

Comment: the "flush valve" is the mechanism that allows tank water to enter the bowl, effecting a "flush", usually on the right. I think you mean the *fill valve* (sometimes called the ballcock valve); the valve that fills the tank and controls tank water height.

Comment: @Iggy Here is the video I recorded of my toilet: https://youtu.be/iFsR5KEpINI

Comment: Great vid! Yeah your Fill Valve's seal or washer is going bad. Turning the water off & back on re-seats it. The flush then unseats it again when the pressure is released. One used to be able to tighten the seal back down with a big nut, but I just checked mine, which the same exact valve & that cheat is gone...planned obsolescence. Definitely get a new Fill Valve & Water Supply (you got it right) hose. Thanks for the vid again, extremely helpful.

Comment: @Iggy I'll get that fixed right away! Thank you for helping!

Comment: Glad to help & happy flushing.

Comment: why do you have to replace the hose as well?

Comment: Just because it's old. The rust on the collar, typically, would indicate that it's over 20-years old. It might make it to 30, but it's better to replace it now (then) than to have a leak or even full-flow burst.