# After I close and open my shutoff valve, my toilet flushes normally, but only once! After 1 normal flush, why does no water flow thru the refill tube?

Tags: toilet

After my toilet  suddenly failed to flush, I took this picture 1.

[image]

1.1. Water was dripping from the black Fill Valve with a Column Float.

1.2. There was no water in the white Refill Tube!

Then I closed and opened the water supply Shutoff Valve, which **AT FIRST BLUSH *APPEARED*** to fix the hitch! See picture 2.

[image]

2.1. No water dripped from the Fill Valve.

2.2. Ta-da! Water was gushing through the Refill Tube!

##### But alas, when I flushed the toilet next time, the hitch at picture 1 relapsed. Again, I had to close and open the Shutoff Valve to respawn at picture 2. Why?!?!

My toilet looks like, but differs from, [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/32052). The differences are the position and kind of Overflow Tube. Mine is covered (the other is UNcovered), and positioned to the upper right (the other is upper left) of the Dual Flush Valve.

Comment: that is one fancy toilet, which one is it

Comment: Is that one of those toilets with a #1 and #2 button on the top for flushing?

Comment: @Ruskes Both pictures show the selfsame toilet!  I don't know this toilet's model information.

Comment: @Huesmann I wrote "dual flush", so yes. The toilet doesn't indicate "#1 and #2" on the buttons though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is classic issue with the fill valve.

You could try to remove the black cover at the top and turn the valve keeper to clean debris from the valve. This may work for a short time, or cure for a long time.
**or**

Just replace the flush valve.  They are relatively inexpensive and available a number of places.

Comment: When I wrote this post, I had already "remove[d] the black cover at the top and turn[ed] the valve keeper to clean debris from the valve." But this didn't fix the toilet! Please elaborate?

Comment: @user61793, replace the fill valve as I stated in my answer.